# Does gson.fromJson create nulls or empty lists when instantiating pojo

Tags: java, gson

I noticed a warning in my editor when I called a getter for a List that is initialized by gson.fromJson. Some of my Json elements have populated lists while others are empty.

Not sure if gson uses the setter to set an empty array or a null when the Json array source is an empty array.

Is best practice to handle exception, check for null before using getter, or override the pojo?

Answer (score 0):

Gson.fromJson returns null if the input string is null which is based on the below code

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public <T> T fromJson(String json, Type typeOfT) throws JsonSyntaxException {
    if (json == null) {
      return null;
    }
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(json);
    T target = (T) fromJson(reader, typeOfT);
    return target;
  }
```

And as you see, the exception JsonSyntaxException will throw if any wrong happens.

So you can wrap a logic to an utility method to handle Exception, null and re-use it across your project.